# Replace XML Data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I have a request to replace the XML property with another tables column value. Currently I'm confused on how to proceed further. I did some investigation but none of the seems to be working for my scenario. Could someone help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

I have the below query

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '<LookupSyndicationExportProfileData Id="-1" Name="">
  <LookupExportScopes IncludeAllLookup="False" IncludeAllLocale="False" GroupBy="ColumnName" FileFormat="Excel10">
    <Locales>
      <Locale PK_Locale="1" ShortName="English World Wide" LongName="" FK_Culture="0" FK_Region="0" FK_Lang="0" />
    </Locales>
    <LookupExportScope Id="0" Name="Brand" />
    <LookupExportScope Id="1" Name="BrandColor" />
    <LookupExportScope Id="2" Name="BrandType" />
  </LookupExportScopes>
</LookupSyndicationExportProfileData>'

SELECT 
    'tblk_' + N.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') NAME,
    N.C.value('@Id', 'nvarchar(100)') Id, 
    ro.Pk_RST_Object 
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('//LookupExportScope') N(C) 
INNER JOIN 
    tb_RST_Object ro ON 'tblk_' + N.C.value('@Name','nvarchar(100)') = ro.Shortname
```

Below is the result of the above query.

[image]

So, I need to update my @XML variable with Id property to the PK_RST_Object value. Please let me know how shall I do this.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this... Your code looks like *you are **reading** from the xml*, but this sentence *I need to update my @XML variable* sounds like you want to **modify** the existing XML. Is this XML just kinda template you want to fill with data from the table?

Comment: Yes,  I want to modify the XML with the data which I have in the table.

Comment: `xml.modify()` allows one update per call... Just to get this clear: Your XML looks like the above and comes along with `<LookupExportScope>`elements. Their name-attribute's value (together with the prefx `tblk_`) is the key for a join to your table `tb_RST_Object`. True so far? Where do you want to put the values you found as `pk_RST_Object`? Please edit the question to add the expected output.